# How to set CORS in Strapi?

Tags: cors, strapi

I am on a Next.js project with a backend with Strapi. I want to set CORS in Strapi. Here is what I've done on the `middleware.js` file:

```
    ` {
        name: 'strapi::cors',
        config: {
          headers: ['Content-Type', 'Authorization', 'Origin', 'Accept'],
          origin: [
            'http://localhost:3000',
            'http://localhost:1337',
             process.env.SITE_URL,
             process.env.SITE_URL_INT,
             process.env.STRAPI_DOMAIN
           ],
          methods: ['GET', 'POST', 'PUT', 'DELETE'],
          keepHeaderOnError: true,
        }
      }`
```

I am still in local but when I am on the port 3001 (to check if my CORS policy is working) i don't have any error CORS error and request are fine (it shouldn't be the case because that's not in the origin).

I want that only the URLs on my origin middleware can access Strapi and make requests to it.